# How to install a software in the particular directory?

Tags: software-installation

How to install a software into a particular directory using dpkg

Answer (score 0):

DPKG has this functionality built-in

```
sudo dpkg -i <package.deb> --root=/media/USBSTICK/
```

If you need to install a bunch of packages that all depend on each other, you list them all at the same time, separated by spaces. The packages (.deb) need to be in the current directory since this does not use apt.

```
man dpkg

--root=dir
Changing root changes instdir to dir and admindir to
dir/var/lib/dpkg.
```

Now, this assumes that there is another Ubuntu system on that stick. You can't install an arbitrary package to other directories than the ones that are specified in the package. The shared libraries on an Ubuntu system have a very specific path.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `"chroot"`. More info on chroot here:
→http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

To do this you need root access...

Open terminal and type → `sudo -i`, then enter your password.

Then type → `# debootstrap chrootname  chrootname-chroot` .

**"Note"→** (`chrootname` = "the name of the directory you want to create".)

Then you can enter the chroot by typing → `# chroot chrootname-chroot`

When you are done just type → `exit`

I hope this helps you... Good luck!

Answer "modified" from here →https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory

Comment: @guntbert Thanks for the edit advise. I learned something new.

Comment: You are welcome, nice to see that at least someone actually reads the edit comments :-))